# Wordpress widget select page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi please tell me where I where I made a mistake ? I would like to add select with page form site. The select already display page but when I update widget select is reload.

```
function form($instance) :

    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select:' ); ?></label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"> 
                <?php           
                    $pages = get_pages( $args );
                    $selected = $instance['link'];
                    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                        $onlyLink = get_page_link( $page->ID );
                        $onlyName = $page->post_title;
                        if ($selected == $page) {
                            echo '<option selected="selected" value="' . $onlyLink . '">'.$onlyName.'</option>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<option  value="' . $onlyLink . '">'.$onlyName.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
function update:

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
        $instance['button_text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['button_text']);   
        $instance['link'] = stripslashes($new_instance['link']);

        return $instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `name` attribute, use `$this->get_field_name()` in its value:

> `<select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php
>   echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>">`

So:

`<select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>">`

[EDIT] **I believe the answer is**:

In the `form()` function, replace:

```
if ($selected == $page)
```

with this:

```
if ($selected == $onlyLink)
```

In addition, you should either define the `$args` variable, or replace the following:

```
$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

with this one:

```
$pages = get_pages();
```

But once again, and please keep this in mind:

> For the name attribute, use `$this->get_field_name()` in its value